# Compress Gzip string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, compression, gzip, deflate

How would I write a method to compress a Gzip string that does not contain a header file, and have it compress to exactly the way it was before I have decompressed it. The original compression is done in C#, and I am inflating in Ruby using the following method:

EDIT: basically, **I would like the matching deflate method** to this inflate:

```
def inflate(string)
    zstream = Zlib::Inflate.new(-Zlib::MAX_WBITS)
    buf = zstream.inflate(string)
    zstream.finish
    zstream.close
    buf
end
```

Before decompressing, the string is:

```
"5\x891\n\xC30\x10\x04{\xBDb\xEB\xE0F&\x81\xA4\xCA3\xDC\xA81\xD2\x1A]\xA1\x13\xB1.\x100\xFEF\xDE\e\x19\x9Cb\x99Yf\xCA\xB3A\x1A,\x13\xB1\x96R\x15I\x96\x85+5\x12\xA2=\xF4:\xAFb\xB9\xD0$\xA2\xF1\xF5>\xDA\xD3\xB9\x9A\xA8f\xFC\xD8\xE6\xFD\x00\x7F\xEB{\f!Uk{\xCF,\x91\xDC\x1C\x10J\xC4\xF7z\xCA\xE8p9\xF8\xFF\xF7\x93\xDEw\xD9\x7F"
```

And after decompressing using inflate, it is:

```
    "What is the common difference in this arithmetic sequence?\n\n\\indenttext{11, 15, 19,\\dots}\n\n\\emcee{\n  \\mc \x964\n  \\mc 2\n *\\mc 4\n  \\mc 8\n  \\mc 11\n  }"
```

I've tried creating multiple deflate methods, but none that can get it back to the original. Thanks for your help!

EDIT: The original compression was done in .NET 2.0 using the following

```
byte[] compressedStringBytes = CompressGzipString(String);
```

and CompressGzipString does:

```
MemoryStream compressed = new MemoryStream();
DeflaterOutputStream zosCompressed = new DeflaterOutputStream(compressed, new Deflater(Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION, true));
zosCompressed.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

If it's not possible to get it to the exact original, what would be the most standardized compression, by which I mean general and that would be able to be decompressed in the same way that the original was?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly how it was compressed in C#?

Comment: Yes, see original post for that info!

Comment: That looks like Java code, not C#.

Comment: @Hyung: The objects used - `CompressGzipString` and `Deflator` - are not part of the standard .NET library.  Where did they come from?

Comment: Ah, sorry. They were written by someone else who was previously working on this project.  

If it cannot be determined how to match the original due to these constraints, as I said, a standardized compression would still function well for me.

Comment: I can't get the compressed data you provided to produce the uncompressed output you provided.  The mix of hex escapes and characters may be messed up somehow.  Can you provide instead a simple hex dump of the compressed data?

Comment: Found the error.  There is a missing space between the \xB9 and the \x9A in your "before decompressing the string is".  You must have inadvertently deleted it.  After adding the space, the "after decompressing" then matches the result of decompressing.

Comment: That compressed string was not produced by .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different compressors, different versions of the same compressor, or the same version of the same compressor with different settings, can and often will produce different output for the same input, even if they all use the same compressed data format (e.g. deflate).  The only thing guaranteed is that when you decompress, you get exactly the same thing back you started with.  In fact, that's really all you need guaranteed.  Why do you want exactly the same compressed stream?

As noted by Ron Warholic, you wouldn't even *want* to get back to the same compressed output from .NET's broken deflate implementation prior to .NET 4.5.  Since .NET 2.0 used its own unique, broken, deflate implementation, you cannot duplicate it with ruby, which uses zlib.

Also as noted by Ron Warholic, ruby and .NET 4.5 or later both use zlib, and so should both produce the same compressed output with the same compression level selected.  Though that is not assured forever, since a new version of zlib may produce different output, and one of ruby or .NET might update to it while the other does not.  Also as noted below, you do not have direct control over the compression level with .NET's classes.

> If it's not possible to get it to the exact original, what would be
>   the most standardized compression, by which I mean general and that
>   would be able to be decompressed in the same way that the original
>   was?

Any correct implementation of lossless compression and decompression will have this property.  You will always get back to the exact original, regardless of how the compressed data may differ.  There is no "most standardized compression".

Your `Zlib::Inflate.new(-Zlib::MAX_WBITS)` is expecting a raw deflate stream, with no header or trailer.  So you would need to produce that on the C# side.

It is not clear from the [.NET documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx) whether the `DeflateStream` class compresses to the deflate format or the zlib format (where the latter is the deflate format with a zlib wrapper, consisting of two prefix bytes and four postfix bytes for data integrity checking).  If it compresses to the deflate format, then it will be compatible with your `Zlib::Inflate.new(-Zlib::MAX_WBITS)`.  If it compresses to the zlib format, then it would be compatible with `Zlib::Inflate.new(Zlib::MAX_WBITS)` (i.e. without the minus sign).  Or you can delete the first two bytes and last four bytes to get back to a deflate stream.

The `DeflateStream` class in .NET is a little odd in that its [`CompressionLevel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.compressionlevel.aspx) is an `enum` with only three options, instead of the ten levels provided by zlib (0..9).  The three options are `Optimal`, `Fastest`, and `NoCompression`.  The last must be 0, the first is probably 9, and the middle one might be 1 or 3.  In any case, there is no option for the default compression level!  That level (6) is a very good balance of compression vs. time.

You might want to consider using [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) instead.  It provides a complete interface to zlib, so that you can specify exactly what you want to do, and know what will happen.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You're right, I don't want the same compressed stream regardless! I would still like to know the equivalent method of what I've posted, however, as I'm not sure how to deflate with the matching option of '-Zlib::MAX_WBITS'. If you could show me that, that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how it was compressed in C# really; before .NET 4.5 the `System.IO.DeflateStream/GZipStream` class in C# used a Microsoft implementation of DEFLATE that differed significantly from zlib (which means you probably can't emulate it easily with zlib).  It was much worse in almost all cases so in .NET 4.5 they replaced it with zlib which *should* be able to match what you can do in Ruby.

If you know what version of C# generated the string you can determine whether or not you can get back to the original bytes.  If it was generated with .NET 4.5 you should be able to do a standard deflate with the same settings to get the same bytes.